# d3.js mouse pointer coordinates when scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a tooltip which appears when the user hovers over the bar chart. It works fine when the svg element is accessed without scrolling the page. But if I scroll and then hover, the position of my tooltip is not working properly.

Here is one example. (On scrolling to the bottom, the tooltip appears somewhere in the middle of the page.)

https://jsfiddle.net/vbgL0ace/47/

```
let main = d3.select("#main")
let data = [{y: 1, name: "John"}, {y: 200, name: "John"}]
let yaxisScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 980]).domain(d3.extent(data, d=> d.y))

function showToolTip(d, coords) {
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("display", "block")
    .text(d.name)
    .style("top", coords[1]+ "px")
    .style("left", coords[0]+ "px");
}

main.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", (d) => yaxisScale(+d.y))
.attr("height", 20)
.attr("width", 200).on("mouseenter", (d) => 
    showToolTip(d, [d3.event.clientX, d3.event.clientY])
)
.on("mousemove", (d) =>
    showToolTip(d, [d3.event.clientX, d3.event.clientY])
)
.on("mouseleave", (d) => d3.select("#tooltip").style("display", "none"));
```

Can someone please help regarding how to fix this tooltip behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clientX` and `clientY` return the position relative to the **viewport** so no account is taken of scrolling.

Try using `pageX` and `pageY` instead which give the position relative to the entire document.

```
.attr("width", 200).on("mouseenter", (d) => 
    showToolTip(d, [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY])
)
.on("mousemove", (d) =>
    showToolTip(d, [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY])
)
```